# Python library to convert .wav file to ogg file

Tags: python-2.7, ogg, wave

Can anyone suggest a Python library (on windows) to convert a `wav` file to an `ogg` file other than [Pymedia](http://pymedia.org/tut/) module. By using Pymedia module I am not able to convert from wav to ogg file.

Using pymedia i can convert a wav to mp3 file,but if i try to convert to other format it throws Just-in-time debugger error please can any one help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post the error encountered using Pymedia?  It might be more of a configuration issue.

Comment: it just gives me this error Pythonw.exe has stopped working..An unhandled win32 exception occurred pythonw.exe[1880].Just in time debugging this exception failed with the following error:No installed debugger has Just in time debugger enabled.

Comment: i used following code to convert wav to ogg http://pymedia.org/tut/src/recode_audio.py.html

Comment: Do you have ogg, vorbis, .. ?

Comment: No what should i install?

Comment: libogg, libvorbis, .... See http://pymedia.org/tut/install_src.html for more.

Comment: i tried to install but it says OGG not fount,VORBIS not found etc..

Comment: can u suggest any other library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `oggenc` http://www.rarewares.org/ogg-oggenc.php

If you're using 64-bit Windows, you can get http://www.rarewares.org/files/ogg/oggenc2.87-1.3.3-x64.zip

(`oggenc -h` gives the usage.)